# I can't see/run Gradle in New Project Wizard/Tool Window

Tags: intellij-idea

So, I have the Gradle plugin installed and enabled, and I even have it installed on my computer, but for some reason, it's still not showing up in the new project wizard. I have no idea why, though I did enabled Maven and it showed up in the new project window instantly. (I'm using windows 10 btw) [My new project wizard window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N00L7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall the IDE from the [downloads page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) and delete `disabled_plugins.txt` file from the [config directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).

Comment: What will deleting the text file do?

Comment: It will enable all the disabled plug-ins.

Comment: Inside `idea.config.path`, the actual location depends on the IDE version and the OS, the linked document describes how you can find it.

Comment: It worked! Though I fully deleted the txt file off of my computer(permanently). Is that a problem?

Comment: No, it will be created again if you disable any plug-ins.

Comment: Why is the "reinstall" step required? Can't you just delete this file from the current installation?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Reinstall can help if a plugin or other IDE files were corrupted for some reason like interrupted patch update. It's not required, but in some cases deleting the file without reinstall will not help.